# Integrate Bot with Direct Line API

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I have a bot developed in SDK 4 and deployed in IIS. When I integrate with web chat using secret it works .

```
     window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
        {
            directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
                secret: 'SECRET CODE'
            }),
            // Passing 'styleOptions' when rendering Web Chat
            styleOptions
        },
        document.getElementById('webchat')
    );
```

But it have very limited styling options in above case. I would like to use REACT which requires token exchange. I am not sure how this will be used? Mean what changes are required at client end & what at Bot end? I cannot find any descriptive document for this. Would be great if we can sample for both at client & Bot end changes for token exchange.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use REACT to style your webchat. The botframework-webchat repo [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) has samples and examples displaying this. For the token exchange, you're going to want to use the following:

```
import { DirectLine } from 'botframework-directlinejs';
import React from 'react';
import ReactWebChat from 'botframework-webchat';

export default class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.directLine = new DirectLine({ token: 'YOUR_DIRECT_LINE_TOKEN' });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactWebChat directLine={ this.directLine } userID='YOUR_USER_ID' />
      element
    );
  }
}
```